# Where is the race condition in this code snippet? (from C# 5.0 in a Nutshell)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

This is from Joseph Albahari's excellent C# 5.0 in a Nutshell book

In one of his chapters, he mentions a race-condition in this code block ..my guess is it's meant to be pretty self-evident, as he didn't bother to specify where it was but running the code multiple times I was unable to produce the said-race condition

```
_button.Click += (sender, args) =>
{
   _button.IsEnabled = false;
   Task.Run (() => Go());
};

void Go()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int result = GetPrimesCount (i * 1000000, 1000000);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (new Action (() =>
       _results.Text += result + " primes between " + (i*1000000) + " and " + 
                                   ((i+1)*1000000-1) + Environment.NewLine));
    }

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (new Action (() => _button.IsEnabled = true));
}
```

Comment: comment out  _button.IsEnabled = false;  Then hammer the button.  Does that show the race condition?

Comment: It occasionally executes them out of sequence, but that would be expected in that case.

Comment: The problem is in the lambda function. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't agree with @Serge's answer. You don't even need multiple threads to see the problem. Try to run your code in its original form and notice the output. For me it's the following and is sometimes random (I fixed the first value):

```
1000000 primes between 5000000 and 5999999
1000000 primes between 5000000 and 5999999
1000000 primes between 5000000 and 5999999
1000000 primes between 5000000 and 5999999
```

Notice the last 2 values. They're all the same, but they should depend on `i`. The problem is not that the operation is not atomic, because the GUI thread will execute the actions sequentially anyway.

The reason for this occurring is that the lambda function passed to `BeginInvoke` takes the value of `i` **at the moment of execution, not at the moment of initialization**, so they will all see the last value of `i` by the time they get executed. The solution is to explicitly pass `i` as a parameter to the lambda like so:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    int result = 1000000;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<int>(j =>
    results.Text += result + " primes between " + (j * 1000000) + " and " +
                              ((j + 1) * 1000000 - 1) + Environment.NewLine), i);
}
```

Comment: I totally missed that! You're right - because i is a "captured variable" that references the same value of i from the loop variable in-scope after the loop queues the delegates ..by assigning it to j ..each thread has it's separate copy. Can't believe I missed that

Although for some reason on my machine, when I execute the code, I don't get that output

Comment: I was talking not about figures it prints out. I was talking about the behavior of '+=' operator when this statement executed concurrently. Is the implementation of this assignment atomic in C#?

Comment: I found the answer for the question in my previous comment: `Aside from the library functions designed for that purpose, there is no guarantee of atomic read-modify-write, such as in the case of increment or decrement.` source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278(v=vs.71).aspx The `+=` operator is `read-modify-write operation`. The type is `string` so producing a result string may cause memory allocation that is a very long process when we are speaking about atomic execution. So I insist on correctness of my arguments

Comment: @Serge: You are correct if the code were to execute in a multithreaded environment. But even if you execute the method from multiple threads, by calling `BeginInvoke` the code of the delegate is forwarded to the GUI thread's event queue, which will execute all the delegates sequentially. So that part of the code does not really execute in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

This line will not be calculated atomically:

```
_results.Text += result + " primes between " + (i*1000000) + " and " + ((i+1)*1000000-1) + Environment.NewLine));
```

So being executed from 5 concurrently running threads it may produce different funny results.

Comment: That intuitively makes sense, but haven't been able to reproduce that.

Is it possible for that to happen? Because won't all the BeginInvokes execute sequentially and thus, won't each delegate be queued sequentially and therefore be dequeued and execute sequentially on the UI thread's message queue?

Comment: "If the unwanted event may occur - it will occur definitely" :)

Comment: I agree Serge, I would definitely say that would be the spot of the race condition ..if 5 concurrently running threads ran it simultaneously, however doesn't the Windows message pump process messages on only one thread? (in effect making each update sequential?)

Comment: I would not recommend you to rely on the properties of the windows message processing. This is probably artificial sample, but still very good. Probably this code may work without the problems even on Win8. But who knows what happens when Win9 will be released?

Comment: Oh I completely agree - I just wanted to confirm whether or not my understanding of how the Windows message processing queue works is correct?

Comment: Oh, well this is another topic)) but as far as I remember, the message queue belongs to the thread, so only owning thread is allowed to poll its queue. But!!! this queue may not be polled in 'serialized' way - you may tell the `GetMessage` function what kind of messages you are interested of. As for the sample, I don't know the details how all this stuff is implemented in C#. I mean dispatching, e.t.c. In fact, I even never read the C# language grammar specification...

Comment: Thanks. Either way the golden rule is - don't make any assumptions about order when it comes to concurrency